What is required to replace a split-AC unit?
We've got an old split AC unit.  It struggles to cool our house (and is noticeably weaker than the other unit we have on the other side of our house), and are thinking of replacing it.
I am a skilled DIY kind of person (hobbyist-level skills at electrical, plumbing, appliance-repaire and woodworking) but obviously not a licensed HVAC/Electrician/Plumber.  What is required in replacing an existing split AC system?  Are most external and internal components similar in terms of what they expect for installation (e.g. electrical and pipe fittings)?  Is there much to do other than just swapping out the two components?  And is handling the refrigerant something a DIY person can do?

Your first question is highly subjective, making it off topic. Questions about cost are also off topic. Please see the [help].

Mainly it depends on your location if you can even touch it.  Quite a few locations require only licensed people to touch refrigerant lines.  You also need special tools that can add to the cost for a one time use.

How difficult is it to swap out a conventional split system? Well.. after the refrigerant is removed, you'll need to be prepared to cut, bend, and braze copper refrigerant tubing. The connections are never positioned exactly the same on the outdoor units and you'll likely need to extend one or both copper tubes a bit. Ports on the evaporator coil are always in a different place. Sometimes there's enough slack in the line set that it can be wrestled into meeting up with the new coil.
If you already have experience with oxy-acetylene welding the brazing copper is not hard, but otherwise, there's a learning curve. It's different enough from sweating copper water pipes and the solder and propane or MAPP gas torch used in sweating aren't suitable for refrigerant work.
Swapping the evaporator coil is often not easy due to duct work. It's almost guaranteed the new coil will not be the same size as the old one so you'll have to figure out how to adjust the ductwork to fill gaps -- or make more room, in case the new coil is larger.
If you're in the USA (and likely other countries) the handling of refrigerant is the sticky part. EPA section 608 requires certification for individuals who handle most refrigerants, record-keeping, and other stuff. So that's the legal side of things. You'd need a refrigerant pump and a recovery cylinder for capturing the refrigerant that's in the existing system.

thanks - sounds like it's not really a DIY project.

There are pre-pressurized systems that are theoretically homeowner installable. (I'm skeptical.)
None are really homeowner removable. The refrigerant must be recaptured and that takes specialized equipment and know-how.
Before replacing the system, have you had a technician evaluate it? It may be worth repairing, and it may be possible to improve, without all the complications and expense of entirely redoing the job.
For that matter, when's the last time you cleaned the dust filters? The fins?

Senville makes a fully DIY systems. They are as easy to install as a toilet or Hot water tank.  However you do need a vacuum pump and a gauge set, but they can be rented.  The refrigerant is contained in the compressor unit and gauged to the size of the wall units.  They work very well.  Removing an old unit has the refrigerant capture issue, so that does complicate things.

Quite a few companies make DIY systems.  If they are legal DIY in your location is the question.  Nasty neighbour 10ft away is much different if they are 500ft away with trees in the way.

@crip659 Proximity to neighbor is 100% irrelevant. Decommissioning the old system in the USA (where the OP is) requires an EPA license, period.

Regrettably, installing a mini split air conditioner is not recommended as a do-it-yourself project.
The difficulty with is that the system should be completely evacuated before adding refrigerant. (Also, the old refrigerant should be pumped out and saved, if feasible, rather than vented to the air.) Failure to remove air from the AC allows moisture to remain, which will freeze inside, causing failure of the system.
HowTo HVAC states, "... manufacturers will have 500 microns listed as the recommended... A good vacuum pump and micron gauge will be needed to read the state of the vacuum." Consider the cost of an effective pump and a trustworthy low-pressure gauge, and consider the effort to learn to use them.
Home Depot has a video on installation. In particular, note comments about "after pressure testing and evacuation," refrigerant is added. The video also states wiring should be performed by a licensed electrician, though local codes may allow DIY wiring to be certified afterwards... or not.

The question is about split system, not mini-split.
